# HTML file Upload To Google Storage With API

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, google-app-engine

I have my Own API and i have a html file same directory with PHP script.

I Want upload this html file to google storage with random name and random bucket

I have some files.

Here is index.php Selecting a file and uploading to Google Storage

```
<?php
    require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
    use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

    $options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'hooliapp.appspot.com' ];
    $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload.php', $options);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Upload to Google Cloud Storage</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <?php if (!empty($_GET['success'])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 
    <form action="<?php echo $upload_url; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form"> 
      Choose your file: <br /> 
      <input name="html" type="file" /> 
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" /> 
    </form> 
    </body> 
    </html> 

     Here is upload.php



           <?php
        require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
        use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
        // get image from Form
        $gs_name = $_FILES["html"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $fileType = $_FILES["html"]["type"]; 
        $fileExt = pathinfo($_FILES['html']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // change name if you want
        $fileName = md5($_FILES['html']['name']).time().".".$fileExt;
        // put to cloud storage
        $file = file_get_contents($gs_name);
        $options = [ "gs" => [ "Content-Type" => $fileType, "acl"=>"public-read" ]];
        $ctx = stream_context_create($options);
        file_put_contents("gs://hooliapp.appspot.com/".$fileName, $file, 0, $ctx);
        // or move 
        //$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://hooliapp.appspot.com/'.$fileName);
        $public_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl('gs://hooliapp.appspot.com/'.$fileName, true);
        echo "Your file url: ".$public_url;
        ?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It may be helpful to look at this section of the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload